# In GitHub action how can I update an environment variable that holds integer?

Tags: github-actions

I'm planning on using matrix to split test load to different shards. I'm trying to collect the number of passed/failed tests by storing it in a environment variable, but when I echo it the variable is still 0 (as it was set).

Could use some help on the subject.

My yaml:

```
name: testsRun

on:
  repository_dispatch:
  schedule:
    - cron: '00 00 * * *'
env:
  TOTAL_FAILS: 0
  TOTAL_PASS: 0
jobs:

  tests:
    name: Run our tests
    strategy:
      max-parallel: 20
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    outputs:
      pass: ${{ env.GITHUB_PASS_COUNTER }}
      fail: ${{ env.GITHUB_FAIL_COUNTER }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Use Node.js 14.x
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: 14.x
          cache: 'npm'
      - run: npm ci
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npx playwright install-deps

      - name: Run tests
        continue-on-error: true
        env:
    
        run: npm install & npx playwright test --browser=chromium --reporter=line,allure-playwright --shard=1/20 2>&1 | tee output.txt 

      - name: Set passed counter to env
        id: runTests1Passed
        run: echo "GITHUB_PASS_COUNTER=$(node libs/countPassFailCI.js passed)" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Echo passed counter
        run: echo ${{ env.GITHUB_PASS_COUNTER }}

      - name: set pass counter
        run: TOTAL_PASS=$(echo $TOTAL_PASS $GITHUB_PASS_COUNTER | awk '{print $1 + $2}')

      - name: Echo TOTAL_PASS
        run: echo ${{ env.TOTAL_PASS }}
```

Comment: You can't create your own variables that start with `GITHUB_` you'll need to pick your own prefix.

Comment: works fine, when I echo "GITHUB_PASS_COUNTER" it shows the number of passing tests: ```Run echo 34
  echo 34
  shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
  env:
    TOTAL_FAILS: 0
    TOTAL_PASS: 0
    GITHUB_PASS_COUNTER: 34```

Comment: You're never setting `TOTAL_PASS` via `>> $GITHUB_ENV`.